# Most-efficient way to copy iPhoto events between computers?

Tags: snow-leopard, macos, photos.app

I experienced a hard-drive crash recently.  While I was able to recover most of the lost photographs from Mozy, some where lost.  Fortunately, the missing photographs are located on another machine.

** edit **

- Computer A: MacBook Pro with Mavericks and iPhoto 9.5.1
- Computer B: Mac Mini with Snow Leopard and iPhoto 9.2.3

I want to preserve the existing photos, faces, and events on computer B (the recovered items), but copy the photos, faces, and events from computer A (the missing items).

What is the most-efficient way to do this?

Comment: Could you explain a little more ? I'm afraid I don't totally get your point

Comment: There are events on computer A that aren't on computer B--they were lost in the crash.  I'd like to copy these events from A to B.  It is easy to *just* copy the photos, but I would like to preserve the meta-data associated with the event and the photographs (e.g. faces).

Comment: maybe this : http://soniq.org/macsoftware/15749/iphoto-export-all-events-to-folders#axzz34Qt1Vix8

Comment: @craig Is there a typo in the question?  It reads "I want to preserve... on computer B, but copy... from computer B".  I was expecting one of those to be "computer A".  Can you clarify?

Comment: @Ashley: You are right: computer A is the source.  I've corrected the question.

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way to accomplish this would be to *merge libraries*. Unfortunately, this is not included as a feature within iPhoto, but can be accomplished using an excellent program, [**iPhoto Library Manager**](http://www.fatcatsoftware.com/iplm/). It's compatible with all versions of iPhoto v8.1.2 or later.

- Your iPhoto Library, by default, is located at: `~/Pictures/iPhoto Library`
- Either place the iPhoto Library of Computer A on an HFS+ formatted external HDD, or use [Target Disk Mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10725) to mount Computer A's HDD as an external drive on computer B. I recommend the former method.

[image]

- Choose Source Library: path to A's library on external HDD
- Choose Destination Library: path to B's library.
- See (3) and (4) for Duplicate Handling and Additional Options, then merge the libraries.

Answer (score 1):

To move the iPhoto Library folder or package to a new location:

1. Quit iPhoto if open.
2. Open your Pictures folder and select the iPhoto Library.
3. Drag the iPhoto Library folder or package to its new location.

If you are using iPhoto ’08 or later, you can double-click the iPhoto Library icon in its new location to open iPhoto. iPhoto will remember this new location in the future.

If you are using iPhoto ’06 or earlier, you will need to follow these steps to tell iPhoto where the Library is now located:

1. Hold down the Option key on the keyboard and open iPhoto.
2. Keep the Option key held down until you are prompted to create or choose an iPhoto Library.
3. Click Choose Library.
4. Locate and select the iPhoto Library in its new location.

Comment: I updated my question.